# File Listener in Ensemble/CachObjectscript

Tags: intersystems-cache, intersystems, intersystems-ensemble, ensemble-learning

I am new to ensemble. I would like to know, whether there is any thing like filesystemwatcher  in Cache/Ensemble. (Note : filesystemwatcher  is in .Net)

My requirement is as follows, My Ensemble production (Business Process) will drop a file in a folder, in that folder a windows service will process the file and replace this file with a new file.

My Business process should wait till the new file is available in the folder and start resuming the process.

Please let me know if this is possible in Ensemble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - the File Inbound Adapter is most likely what you are looking for.  See http://docs.intersystems.com/ens20141/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=EFIL_inbound for details.

Comment: thanks for your reply, what I understood about fileInboundadapter is that it is used with business service. But I am looking for a filewatcher that can be used in a business process. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Instead of trying to make a BP wait for a file processed. It would be a much cleaner design if you were to split your workflow in two. The pause you are describing lends itself as a natural breaking point, both reducing complexity and increasing durability. What would happen if your BP gets interrupted while waiting for a file to be processed? Your computer crashes etc? Splitting this up allows you to use the existing components. The alternative would be to use code of the File Adapter and put it in your BP manually (entirely possible, but might end up being ugly ;) )

Comment: thanks for the clarifications, will try to split the work flow in to two.